# android Gradle sync error (match version)

Tags: java, android, gradle

hey guys im getting this gradle sync error since two days :

Error:Could not find any version that matches com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.01.0.+.

 here is the gradle files :

```
println "-------------------------------------------------"
println "Build ResideMenu with:\n\tbuildToolsVersion = " +     
System.properties['buildToolsVersion']
println "\tandroidGradlePluginVersion = " +     System.properties['androidGradlePluginVersion']
println "\tfile.encoding = " + System.properties['file.encoding']
println "\tCharset.defaultCharset() = " + java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().toString()
println "-------------------------------------------------\n"


 ext {
compileSdkVersion = 19
buildToolsVersion = System.properties['buildToolsVersion']
minSdkVersion = 9
targetSdkVersion = 14
      }

 buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' + System.properties['androidGradlePluginVersion']
}
  }

 allprojects {

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to add to the end of the dependency but it should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
```